# Android get IllegalStateException for custom Database Handler

Tags: android, android-sqlite

in one of my custom database handler i get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: /data/data/com.sample/databases/sample {0}
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
```

after any searvh in google and this site i can not found whats problem of this code :

```
public String getFirstItemReceived(String username){
        db = this.getReadableDatabase ();
        String mLastID = "";
        String query = "SELECT * from "+ this.RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE +" WHERE userID = '"+username+"' ORDER BY lastId DESC";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst ();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            mLastID       = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastId"));
        }
        cursor.close ();
        return mLastID;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SDCARD_DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)` befor accessing the db function? and try to open cursor also. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change "how to acces database" with Singleton Pattern style for avoiding error like that

You can read how to do that from these blog

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html